# Does the version of Oracle ODP.Net need to match the database version

Tags: .net, oracle

When using Oracle Data Access Components for .NET 4.x (that is, not .Net Core), do you need to use a version that matches the version of the Oracle database?

For example, we are using ODAC 18.1 against Oracle 11.2.0.4.  Is that supported and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't have to match but there are limitations. Typically Oracle Client and Oracle Database are working together by +/- 2 versions.

As a rule of thump that means the Oracle 18.1 (i.e. 13.1) ODP.NET client works together with database down to version 11.1

Check the [System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/odpnt/InstallSystemRequirements.html#GUID-A6405CAD-C0E9-45E0-9C38-26B7ED214479) where is says:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver requires the following:
>
> - Same Windows operating system support as ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver.
> - ODP.NET, Managed Driver is built with AnyCPU. It runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) Windows and on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64)
>     .NET Framework.
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6.x, or 4.7.x.
> - **Access to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 or later**

So, Oracle database version 11.2.0.4 is fine - but it is the oldest release which is still working.